# Sharepoint Security Question Deletion

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, list, security, share

How to allow a top-level user to delete items but not folders, or columns?
How to go around with this?

Comment: What do you mean by "top-level user"? What permissions are granted to this user? Which all operations you want to allow to this user like create/update/delete, changing list settings, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint, folders are items. The "Delete Items" permission applies to folder and documents in a library. It's not possible to specify this permission level based on the content type, without maybe a myriad of unique item level permissions (which I would not recommend).

With regards to deleting columns from a library, only those with "Manage Lists" permission can do this e.g. the Edit permission level

Deleting column values relating to an individual item require the "Edit items" permission.